# css display none on specific page, without page id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'd like to hide a column in css for only one specific page and i saw several options for it, but every one uses page id. What if two pages have the same id and the differences are only in the class definitions?
I want to use the 'display none' tag only on /*Page 2*/.
Here is the example:

/*Page1*/

```
<body id="body" class="bootstrap-body page-body home_body body-admin-logged" role="document">
```

/*Page 2*/

```
<body id="body" class="bootstrap-body page-body list_page_body category_list_body body-pathway-top body-admin-logged" role="document">
```

/*Column - Page2*/
The html code

```
<aside class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 column-left">
```

/*Column-Page2*/ css code

```
.column-content-left, .column-left {
    float: left;
}
```

If I use the display none in the css above, it will works perfectly. The problem is that it reflects on */Page1*/ too.

Is it possible to do that in css or javascript, without accessing the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the body css too like this:

```
body.list_page_body .column-content-left, body.list_page_body .column-left {
    display: none;
}
```

This should only trigger for the `body` with the class `.list_page_body` (or you can use another class specific to that page.

Comment: Just the same. Reflects on Page1. If it helps the html for the column in Page1 is: <aside class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 column-left>

Comment: I've edited my answer. Didn't saw the "," between the css rules

Comment: Working. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Use a class unique to the second page, for example list_page_body and in your css

```
.list_page_body .column-content-left, .list_page_body .column-left
{
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible in javascript. Just get the url of the page using `window.location.href` and add a class or something if it's the page you want the special treatment on.

Answer (score 0):

The classes that distinguish page 2 from page one are: `list_page_body` `category_list_body` and `body-pathway-top`. So you can use any of them to implement your CSS on page 2 without effecting page 1.

Example:

```
body.category_list_body .column-left{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with jQuery by aiming the url path

```
 jQuery(function ($){
        var pathname = window.location.pathname;
        if (pathname == "/page2/"){
           $(".column-class").css("display","none");
          }
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

If page 2's body tag has a unique class, you can use the `.parent .child {}` CSS selector. From what you've provided:

```
body.list_page_body .column-content-left, body.list_page_body .column-content-left {
    display: none;
}
```

Just so you know, with parent / child selectors, you can use either `.parent .child` or `.parent > .child`. The former would select all instances within `.parent` that the `.child` class is used in the document:

```
<body class="parent">
  <div class="child">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In the example above, `.parent .child {}` would apply rules to both the initial `.child` as well as the nested `.child`.

The latter `.parent > .child` applies to only direct descendants. Using the same example above, only the initial .child element would be selected by `.parent > .child`. The nested `.child` wouldn't be affected.